# Image is loaded but not showing in localhost application on firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, show

I already googled this problem and I found several answers. Most of them recommended to clean cache and cookies, which I did but it didn't work.

I want to display an image in my application. When I check the developer settings in Firefox, my image is loaded, but it doesn't show. It also says, its content is 0x20, even if I set the width and height to 100px and 80px. I even tried with the !important statement, but it still shows 0x20.

[image]

In Google Chrome it works totally fine but in Firefox it doesn't.

This problem actually seems pretty easy to solve but I really can't find out why it won't work and I tried so many options but none of them seem to work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

html

```
<i class="icon"></i>
```

css

```
.icon {
     width: 100px;
     height: 80px;
     content: url(../imgs/icon.png);
 }
```

Comment: It might be a CSS problem, if the image is loaded

Comment: please add also html example code

Comment: I posted my code. But I dunno if it's really about this because in Google Chrome it works.

Comment: Did you use font-awesome.css?

Comment: check your image URL is correct?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya yes it is. I mean it works in Google Chrome. And with the answer below I managed to show the image but the size of the image is not correct yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add a `content` to some element.

`content` is only supported by `:before` and `:after`. See [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp).

And `<i>` is an `inline` element, for giving it width/height through css add it as `inline-block`.

Change your CSS to the following should work, maybe add a `display: inline-block;`

```
.icon:before {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    content: url(../imgs/icon.png);
}
```

This will change the size of the before, only when using responsive SVGs the image size will change.

I prefer to use a `background` approach:

HTML:

```
<i class="icon"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
}
.icon:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(//via.placeholder.com/150x75) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

This will change the image according to the container size. With `background-size: contain` the proportions are preserved. A `content` is needed when using `before`.

[Try out.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoyvJj)

Comment: The image is shown now, but now I can't adjust the size, even though I tried with display: inline-block. Any other idea how I could adjust the size?

Comment: I just changed the size of the image now.

Comment: @BlueCat keep in mind that the image should be (depending on target platforms) bigger than it is displayed, especially if you want clear and sharp images on retina/high ppi screens. If possible try to use only svg.